# Is there any way to get Shield Block reaction through a class or ancestry feat?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e

I want Shield Block reaction for a Kobold Barbarian. If the feat works for more builds, it is even better.

Is it possible to get Shield Block through a *class* or *ancestry* feat?

I found Viking Weapon Familiarity, but it requires Viking Dedication. 2 feats are a steep price, is there anything simpler?

Comment: Are your General Feats too important for you to get it the "normal" way?

Comment: I want Adopted Ancestry with my first general feat

Comment: Which is your adopted ancestry? You can get it with your 5th level Ancestry Feat if you pick human... although I'm guessing that Feat is earmarked for something else from your Adoptive heritage

Comment: @Ifusaso, it is Gnome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

There is (currently) no way for a *Kobold* to gain Shield Block without spending a General Feat on it, except for Viking Weapon Familiarity, as you've noted.

As always, it's hard to prove a negative. But I have searched both Shield Block and General Feat through all the class and other Archetypes and Ancestries, as well as for options that would allow a Kobold to dip into a second Ancestry, like Halflings can.